# Eclipse - CDT - Locked form

Tags: eclipse, settings, eclipse-cdt

In the project properties I have an locked form: [image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25397982/eclipseerror.png]
How can I change this settings, or unlock the form?

Comment: What toolchain are you using? I just checked the sources and this enablement is governed by the toolchain.

Comment: It's are windows specific bug. [You can found answer here.](http://rtorsten.blogspot.com/2012/05/eclipse-cdt-disabled-build-settings.html)